# Change static file serving to nginx from flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I am running my flask project in nginx. This is the conf file

```
server {

   listen  80;
   server_name site.in;
   root /root/site-demo/;
   access_log /var/log/site/access_log;
   error_log /var/log/site/error_log;

   location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
      proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:4000 http://site.in;
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }

}
```

When i tried to put the expires part for static files into the conf it failed. I read that this may be due to the fact that the static files are served by flask rather than nginx. If so what changes should i bring to the above conf file so that the static file serving can be done by nginx for my project.

As per the answer i changed the conf as below. Now all static file shows 403 error.

```
server {

   listen  80;
   server_name site.in;
   root /root/site-demo/;
   access_log /var/log/site/access_log;
   error_log /var/log/site/error_log;

   location / {
      proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:4000/;
      proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:4000 http://site.in;
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   }
   location  /static {
      alias /root/site-demo/static;
      autoindex on;
      expires max;
   } 

}
```

Comment: Static files are not served by Flask.

Comment: So you now have a permissions issue. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Who is the `user` set to in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: You could use the `namei -om /root/site-demo/static` command line command to see the permissions of these folders.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x root root     / -------
 drwx------ root root     root ----------
 drwxr-xr-x 777  www-data site-demo ---------
 drwxrwxrwx 777  www-data static


This is the output i got. www-data is the owner i think

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your **nginx** configuration:

```
    location  /static {
        alias /path/to/your/static/folder;
        autoindex on;
        expires max;
    }
```

**EDIT**

**nginx** requires the whole tree to be readable and not just where your root starts in nginx.conf. So the command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /root/site-demo/static
```

should solve the permissions problem. But, I think, is not a good thing - for security reasons - to put your site in the `/root` directory of your web server. Usually a site is put under the `/var/www` folder.

**P.S.**

The `chmod -R 777` command gives owner, group and others permission to read, write and execute files in a folder and in all its subfolders.

Comment: Changing permissions not solving the permission problem. I tried it. Still showing 403

Answer (score 0):

check your nginx configuration here:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
/etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

I was experiencing the same issue you describe
Noticed that I had several configuration files
Leaving only one config file fixed
This site is also helpful:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/

Answer (score 0):

if you run on server or docker ,you should do like that:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name sample.xx.code;
    location /{
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location  /static {
      proxy_pass http://video/static;
      expires max;
    }
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
}
```